# A sci-fi music video where there’s one guy with one big eye who runs away from people with mouths for a head

Tags: music-identification, music-video

So I know it’s weird. I’m pretty sure it was in English. I don’t remember the music style but I’ve been looking for this clip for like 15years now… it was on TV so I guess it’s not that edgy? And I’m pretty sure it wasn’t *The Residents*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Which country did you watch this in? Also, you said you've been looking for this video for around 15 years, so does that you mean you first saw it circa 2006?

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing this. Any chance of a sketch?

Comment: No… I can’t find anything… hellish landscape, eye-guy falls into some kind of hole at one point, while the others chase him

Comment: Was it cartoon-like or 3d animation?

Comment: Cyclops - Eye of the Storm/Night of the Cyclops https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d73z6qI1vWg ?

Comment: I think it was 3D! 
And no it’s not Cyclops either…